# Magento 2 : File upload form front end in Custom Module

Tags: magento2, extensions, file-upload

I am getting this error when I submit the form from the front end. Although I set the required extension in the **setAllowedExtensions**

> Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Disallowed file type.

```
if($files!='')
    {
        foreach ($files as $key => $value) {

            $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $key]);
            $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png','pdf', 'docx', 'doc']);
            $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
            /* start of validated image */
            $uploaderFactory->addValidateCallback('custom_image_upload',
                $imageAdapter,'validateUploadFile');
            $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('custom_module');
            $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);

            $imagepath = $result['file'];
            //print_r($imagepath);exit;

            $saveData['custom_file'] = $imagepath;
            //$this->model->setData($saveData);

            //$submitModel->setData($saveData);
            //$submitModel->save();
        }
    }
```

> When I upload a **jpeg** or **png it** works fine ,but gives error on **doc,docx** and **pdf**

Comment: Comment out $uploaderFactory->addValidateCallback('custom_image_upload',
                $imageAdapter,'validateUploadFile');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with following code

```
$uploaderFactory->addValidateCallback('custom_image_upload',
                $imageAdapter,'validateUploadFile');
```

You are using the Image Adapter factory that will not allow you upload the files. You can use File Uploader instead.

```
Magento\Framework\File\Uploader
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this function to your class

```
private function validateUploadFile($filePath)
{
     return;
    // @todo
    // your custom validation code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code

```
$uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png','pdf', 'docx', 'doc'));
```

instead of

```
$uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png','pdf', 'docx', 'doc']);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: are u sure !!!!