# Create upload For Pdf

Tags: magento2

this is my code

```
public function uploadpdf($name)
    {

            $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
                'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
                ['fileId' => $name]
            );

            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['pdf']);

            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
            $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();

            $uploader->addValidateCallback($name, $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);

            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
            $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                                   ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('partcenter/product'));
            $a= 'partcenter/product'.$result['file'];
            return $a;

    }
```

but when i upload pdf its always say disallow file format

Comment: already answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224221/magento-2-file-upload-form-front-end-in-custom-module/224228#224228

Comment: $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
    'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
    ['fileId' => $name]
   );

Comment: not working still error come

Comment: comment this line `$uploader->addValidateCallback($name, $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');` and this check.

Comment: you define in xml file ?